# Creating a c# function to compare int results

Tags: c#, function

This will be so easy for some of you programming geniuses out there but I am a student who recently began learning about C# (and programming in general) and I find myself.... stuck.

This is an assessment I am working on so I am not looking for a copy/paste answer, it would be preferable if I could find out where I am going wrong/where to start so I can fix it myself.

The aim of the assessment is to:

1. use the random number generator to generate 4 numbers - 2 for player 1 and 2 for the dealer.
2. Add players 2 numbers together, add dealers 2 numbers together (show results on screen)

   this is where I become stuck...
3. I need to create a function that basically says:

   - If DealerResult is > PlayerResult display: Dealer Wins.
   - If PlayerResult > DealerResult, display: You win.
   - If DealerResult == PlayerResult display: it is a draw.

So far I have the following code. As you will see, I can generate the numbers, add them together and display the results on screen.

```
using System;

namespace Assessment
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            //Decalre Variables
            Random r = new Random ();
            int PlayerNumber1 = r.Next (6, 25);
            int PlayerNumber2 = r.Next (6, 25);
            int DealerNumber1 = r.Next (6, 25);
            int DealerNumber2 = r.Next (6, 25);
            int PlayerTotal = (PlayerNumber1 + PlayerNumber2);
            int DealerTotal = (DealerNumber1 + DealerNumber2);


            Console.WriteLine ("Welcome!");
            Console.ReadLine ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Your total is: " + PlayerTotal);
            Console.ReadLine ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Dealer total is: " + DealerTotal);
            Console.ReadLine ();


        }

    }
}
```

From here, I am stuck. Suggestions would be so appreciated as to how I should proceed to compare the numbers and display the appropriate result/s through a function.

As mentioned earlier, this is an assessment so I am not looking for a quick fix or final answer. Also, the assessment requires the use of a FUNCTION to generate the result, not a loop or any other type of programming magic that some of you super-geniuses may be aware of. (And I say that with envy - I wish I was half as smart as some of the people I see posting on here). :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You've posted a very well-written question: you've explained what your problem is, shown the code that you've written so far, and provided your thoughts. The only thing you may want to add yet, is what code have you tried that didn't work. But for your first post, well done! +1

Comment: Additionally, you aren't looking for an answer, just help in a direction... which I'm sure you're going to get quickly.

Comment: +1 This is a very well written question that is looking to learn, instead of just get a quick answer. A trait among new programmers that will serve you well.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the encouragement guys. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @NicoleHaines One more thing to do, to complete the loop - if you're happy with one of the answers, mark it as accepted by checking the checkbox to the left of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need simple if statements, and put them into a function:

```
private static void DisplayResult(int playerTotal, int dealerTotal)
{
   if(playerTotal > dealerTotal)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("You win!");
   }
   else if(playerTotal < dealerTotal)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Dealer wins!");
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Draw!");
   } 
}
```

**Explanation:** We create a function that takes two `int` parameter.One of them is `playerTotal`, another is `dealerTotal`.The function compare these values and display the proper result in the console according to this comparison.After you create your function all you need to do is pass  `PlayerTotal` and `DealerTotal` variables to your function like this:

```
 DisplayResult(PlayerTotal, DealerTotal);
```

*Note:* You should put this method into *MainClass*

Comment: Incredible - thank you. I now have a fully functional code. This may seem so silly but being very new to all of this, I didn't realize that the if, else if, else statement was a PART of a function. I thought I would need to do the calculations myself within the function and return the values into new variables and return those for the screen output. I hope that makes sense. But your answer was so clear and so helpful I understood the "why" behind the "how" - something I struggle with all the time. Thanks Selman22! :)

Comment: @NicoleHaines you are welcome.by the way you can return a value from your function.this is just one of the possible ways.If you wish instead of using `Console.WriteLine` you can return the message as a `string` then display it inside of `Main` method with `Console.WriteLine`.Also there are so many things here that I didn't mention with details.You should probably read documentation or a book and learn all of the details about `if else-if statements`,`method definitions`,`access modifiers` etc.one  answer is not enough to explain all of this :)

Answer (score 2):

To start you will need a function. Functions look like this:

```
<access modifier> <return type> <Name> ( <parameters> )    
{}
```

A quick example:

```
private bool GetResult (int playerValue, int dealerValue)
{
}
```

What this means is that the function will return a bool, and it takes two int parameters.
To return nothing, return void. To call the function, use its name and pass the parameters inside the parenthesis:

```
bool result = GetResult(1, 2);
```

Now to do a comparison, we use the if statement:

```
if (<expression> <comparator> <expression>)   
{}
```

Another quick example:

```
if (playerScore > dealerScore)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Player wins!");
}
```

Which says, "If PlayerScore is greater than DealerScore, do what is inside the brace" (a print in this case).

I'm trying to explain the basics, instead of give an actual answer, as you requested. Please let me know if I can clarify anything better, and good luck learning programming in C#!

Comment: Amazing, I have actually printed this and pinned it on the wall next to my desk! Trying to get my head around the foundations and fundamentals is proving to be quite challenging - having a reference like this will be great for reviewing and revising the most common elements of programming. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another variation demonstrating function returning result as a string.

```
 
using System;
```

namespace Assessment
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Decalre Variables
            Random r = new Random();
            int PlayerNumber1 = r.Next(6, 25);
            int PlayerNumber2 = r.Next(6, 25);
            int DealerNumber1 = r.Next(6, 25);
            int DealerNumber2 = r.Next(6, 25);
            int PlayerTotal = (PlayerNumber1 + PlayerNumber2);
            int DealerTotal = (DealerNumber1 + DealerNumber2);

```
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome!");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Your total is: " + PlayerTotal);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Dealer total is: " + DealerTotal);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Dealer total is: " + DealerTotal);
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine(DisplayResult(PlayerTotal, DealerTotal));

        Console.ReadLine();



    }

    private static string  DisplayResult(int playerTotal, int dealerTotal)
    {
        var result = "An unhandled exception has occured ";

        if (playerTotal > dealerTotal)
        {
            result = "You win!";
        }
        else if (playerTotal < dealerTotal)
        {
            result = "Dealer wins!";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Draw!";
        }

        return result; 
    }

}
```

}